# How do I make sure an association's attribute is correct to validate the association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a simple user:  **Edited a bit for clarity, and on Sam's suggestion

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # <snip other attribs>
  has_many :handles
  has_one :active_handle, :class_name => "Handle"

  validates_each :active_handle, :allow_nil => true  do |record, attr, value|
    record.errors.add attr, "is not owned by the correct user" unless record.handles.include?(value)
  end
end
```

And a handle model:

```
class Handle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :user_id
  validates :user_id,
        :presence => true,
        :numericality => true

  attr_accessible :name
  validates :name,
        #etc...
end
```

Now I'd like to check, when setting the User.active_handle association, that the handle is owned by the correct Handle.user_id.  I've tried to do this in a custom validation, and also in a validate method on the User model.  Both ways, it does the exact opposite of what I want, it sets the user_id of handle to the User doing the checking.

I'm at the end of my rope, clearly I don't understand something, and google isn't getting me anywhere I haven't already been.

ETA:  I have also tried to manipulate the has_one association with conditions, that seems to fail too...

```
has_one :active_handle,
        :class_name => "Handle",
        :conditions => ['user_id =?', '#{self.id}']
```

Comment: So users can have many handles and you want to check that the user has the handle before it because the `active_handle`. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, do how are you updating the `active_handle`? Are you doing it from a user object or from the handle object. Or in other words, what controller are you trying to update the `active_handle` from?

Comment: Correct, currently I'm trying to do it from the User controller.

Comment: I think I'm getting to the fact that the association is updating and because handle belongs_to :user it's updating that association before validation, thus there is possibly no way to do what I want?  I've also tried to tweak the association :conditions with little luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a different approach to this problem; the double link is messy, and hard to maintain, as you've discovered.  Instead, I'd put an active flag in the handle model, and order the `:active_handle` association on that flag:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :handles
    has_one  :active_handle, :class_name => 'Handle', :order => 'handles.active DESC'
end
```

Now there's only one link, and it's the same link that's already in place to establish the plain `has_many :handles` association (namely, the `user_id` attribute in the Handle model).  Finding the active handle in now just a matter of finding the User's first Handle with the active flag set.  And I'd use `:order` rather that `:conditions`, as that'll give you a nice fallback:  If no Handle for that user has the active flag set, Rails'll pick one to use as a default.

And then, in your handle model, you can have a fairly simple activate function:

```
class Handle < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ...stuff...

    def activate!
        # Pseudocode - sorry!
        sql('UPDATE handles SET active = 0 WHERE user_id = ?', self.user_id)
        self.active = true
        self.save!
    end
end
```

Or, if you wanted to be able to call something like `user.handles.activate(hdl)`, you could put something similar as an association extension.  Or `user.active_handle = hdl`.  Or...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic, ok, that's the missing key I think, I didn't know I could use order like that.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

If your doing it from the user model then you need to add the validation to the user model instead of the handle model because the user is what's getting updated.

This is how I would validate that the user actually belongs to the handle before it can be made active.

```
class Handle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :handles
  validates :handle_can_be_active?

  def handle_can_be_active?
      if self.handles.include?(self.active_handle)
          #no problem
      else
          errors.add_to_base('Must belong to the handle before it can be active!')
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think I didn't make it clear that the validation method was happening in the user model, but I will try and see.